# Could not connect pentaho with oracle

Tags: java, oracle, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKB5T.png)

this is my first time to use pentaho woth oracle. I tried to add ojdbc8.jar file into /lib but nothing changed. Can someone help on how to connect them

I tried to add ojdbc8.jar file into /lib but nothing changed. I expect there is a problem with my java installed

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: RDB is not that driver.

Comment: Do not include links to images and do not include images of text/code.

Answer (score 0):

As @OldProgrammer has stated, you are not using the correct driver, with the ojdbc8.jar driver library, you have to use the Oracle (without RDB) driver:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure the version of ojdbc is compatible with the version of the oracle database, I already had a similar problem that resolved when returning to ojdbc 6